# Prove that Christoffel symbols are zero on $U$.

Tags: differential-geometry

> Let $M^n$ be a flat manifold. Consider a chart $(U,x)$ so that $x:U\subset \mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow x(U)$ is an isometry. Prove that Christoffel symbols are zero on $U$.

I am new to differential Geometry. So I have no idea how to start. The only thing that I know is $\nabla_{X_j}X_i=\sum_k \Gamma_{ij}^k X_k$ where $X_i=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ is a basis for $T_pM$ for $p\in x(U)$. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It is straight forward. If $M$ is flat, there is a local isometry to Euclidean space, so the metric is preserved in any chart. The Christoffel symbols can be computed from the derivative of the metric. But the flat metric is all constants - 1's and 0's. So taking these derivatives make the Christoffel symbols all identically 0.

Edit: The intrinsic formula can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christoffel_symbols#Christoffel_symbols_of_the_second_kind_.28symmetric_definition.29).

Comment: It'd be really funny to me if you were in my differential geometry class. 533?